# Writing a Boolean -> string mapper with precedence in a declarative way using Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How do I write this code in a more functional/declarative way?

```
type FieldType = "dropdown" | "text" | "file" | null;
const getFieldType = (field: {isDropdown?: boolean, isTextInput?: boolean, isFileModal?: boolean}) => {
// a field can have all 3 of the above boolean properties at once as "true"
//but some of them are more important than others - eg. isDropdown
//hence the if/else if below
if(field.isDropdown) {
  return 'dropdown';
} else if(field.isTextInput) {
  return 'text';
}
else if (field.isFileModal) {
  return 'file';
}
}
```

My solution:

```
const getFieldType = (field) => {
  const mapConditionToType = [
    [field.isDropdown, 'dropdown'],
    [field.isTextInput, 'text'],
    [field.isFileModal, 'file']
  ]

  return mapConditionToType.find([condition, type] => condition)?.type ?? null;
}
```

As you can see it doesn't contain ... any Ramda at all. I was wondering if it's possible to write this in a more declarative way using functional programming?

Comment: Can `Field` be `isDropdown: true` and at the same time `isTextInput: true` ?

Comment: Yes. See my comment in the first code block "a field can have all 3 of the ...". But you're right I didn't mention they can all be true :P

Comment: But `find` will return first occurrence, not all. What the expected behaviour if all three props are true?

Comment: The expected behavior is that the first matching element is returned. "isDropdown" is more important than "isTextInput" and so on.

Comment: Hmmm, R.cond looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in @walnut_salami's comment, **cond** is the right operator to use in the case.  You can use more advanced operators to test for truthiness in the first parameter, but since the properties being checked return truthy values, the **prop** operator should be sufficient.

```
interface Field  {
  isDropdown?: boolean;
  isTextInput?: boolean;
  isFileModal?: boolean;
}

const getFieldType = cond<Field, FieldType>([
  [prop('isDropdown'), always('dropdown') ],
  [prop('isTextInput'), always('text') ],
  [prop('isFileModal'), always('file') ],
  [T, always(null)]
]);

console.log(getFieldType({ isDropdown: true })); // dropdown
console.log(getFieldType({ isTextInput: true })); // text
console.log(getFieldType({ isFileModal: true })); // file
console.log(getFieldType({ })); // null
console.log(getFieldType({ isTextInput: true, isDropdown: true })); // dropdown
```

Since you're using TypesSript, you can take advantage of the the overload of **cond** that accepts arguments for the subject type and return type.  By doing so you and refactoring to **Field** and **FieldType** will throw compiler errors if they somehow break what is being used in the operators.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to leverage some declarative library, such as [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)

````js
/**
 @typescript ```
   R.cond<Record<string, boolean>, FieldType>([ ... ]);
   ```
**/
const getFieldType = R.cond([
  
  [R.prop('isDropdown'), R.always('dropdown')],
  [R.prop('isTextInput'), R.always('text')],
  [R.prop('isFileModal'), R.always('file')],
  [R.T, R.always(null)],

]);

console.log(
  'it should return "dropdown" =>',
  getFieldType({ isDropdown: true }),
)

console.log(
  'it should return "file" =>',
  getFieldType({ isFileModal: true }),
)

console.log(
  'it should return "text" =>',
  getFieldType({ isTextInput: true }),
)

console.log(
  'it should return "null" =>',
  getFieldType({ isMultiSelect: true }),
)
````

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.cond` fits the structure of the array of pairs you wish to supply. You can use `R.pipe` to generate a function that accepts an array of pairs, and then produces a new function based on `R.cond` (test cases from [Daniel Gimenez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999838/5157454)):

```js
const { pipe, map, evolve, prop, always, append, T, cond } = R

const createGetFieldType = pipe(
  map(evolve([prop, always])), // wrap each element in the pairs with the relevant function
  append([T, always(null)]), // add the default value
  cond // partially apply to cond
)

const getFieldType = createGetFieldType([
  ['isDropdown', 'dropdown'],
  ['isTextInput', 'text'],
  ['isFileModal', 'file']
])

console.log(getFieldType({ isDropdown: true })); // dropdown
console.log(getFieldType({ isTextInput: true })); // text
console.log(getFieldType({ isFileModal: true })); // file
console.log(getFieldType({ })); // null
console.log(getFieldType({ isTextInput: true, isDropdown: true })); // dropdown
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```